# (UWP) How to activate the "Taskbar Miniplayer" like in Groove

Tags: background, media-player, uwp, windows-10-universal

I use the BackgroundMediaPlayer for my App to play Audio in the Background. Now i see these buttons:

[image: Buttons]

How can i activate them?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the media controls from the taskbar to work, you need to load and configure the SystemMediaTransportControls from the foreground application AND the background task. If you are doing it only from the background task, the controls will be displayed but they will remain disabled.

In your foreground application, you should have the following code:

```
var smtc = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
smtc.ButtonPressed += smtc_ButtonPressed;
smtc.PropertyChanged += smtc_PropertyChanged;
smtc.IsEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPauseEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPlayEnabled = true;
smtc.IsNextEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPreviousEnabled = true;
```

And in the background task, you should have :

```
smtc = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls;
smtc.ButtonPressed += smtc_ButtonPressed;
smtc.PropertyChanged += smtc_PropertyChanged;
smtc.IsEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPauseEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPlayEnabled = true;
smtc.IsNextEnabled = true;
smtc.IsPreviousEnabled = true;
```

Beware that the API to get the control instance is not the same:
[SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.getforcurrentview.aspx)
 in the foreground app and  [BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn926635(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.systemmediatransportcontrols)%3Bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3Dv5.0)%3Bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true) in the background task.

You will have to support the button pressed event in the two (foreground + background)

Comment: Hi, is this method still work in 2 process model for background audio? because in my case system player controls don't work when the app goes to background even though audio keeps playing. Do we need to change anything after launch of one process model for background audio. ps- consider i can't switch my entire app from 2 process model to single process model. *help appreciated*

Comment: This should still work. The two process model is deprecated but still working. You should share what you've done to investigate further. There some good explanations [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/01/13/the-basics-of-background-audio/)

Answer (score 1):

That's [System Media Transport Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls) and you should add code to handle click event.
Here is official sample:

```
public MainPage()
{
this.InitializeComponent();

// Hook up app to system transport controls.
systemMediaControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
systemMediaControls.ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;

// Register to handle the following system transpot control buttons.
systemMediaControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
systemMediaControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
}

async void SystemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender,
SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
{
switch (args.Button)
  {
    case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            mediaElement.Play();
        });
        break;
    case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            mediaElement.Pause();
        });
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```