# How to add tranport control button to taskbar preview window

Tags: uwp, media-player

I'm using `MediaPlayerElement`, and I want to add Play/Pause/Next....button to taskbar preview window, as the following picture shows.

I tried the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786261/uwp-how-to-activate-the-taskbar-miniplayer-like-in-groove), sadly it doesn't work.
I also tried [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls), doesn't work either.

[image]

My following code is

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/elephantsdream-clip-h264_sd-aac_eng-aac_spa-aac_eng_commentary-srt_eng-srt_por-srt_swe.mkv"));
player.Source = source;
player.MediaOpened += Player_MediaOpened;
MyPlayer.SetMediaPlayer(player);

//var systemMediaTransportControls = player.SystemMediaTransportControls;
var systemMediaTransportControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
systemMediaTransportControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
systemMediaTransportControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
systemMediaTransportControls.ButtonPressed += SystemMediaTransportControls_ButtonPressed;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from your screenshot, we can find the control button on the taskbar preview. And there are system level, if we enable the [**Background Media Playback**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio) capability in the `packagemanifest` file, the buttons will display.

Comment: Thanks. I will post a feed back to the doc and point this out.